# How do I join two tables to get statistics

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL database with two tables in it:

```
Members
 - id, name, city_id
```

and:

```
Cities
- id, name
```

I want a query that will return each city name and how many members are in it.

The output I need is:

```
city_name    count
------------------
New York     15
Los Angeles  20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(DISTINCT b.city_id) 
FROM Cities a JOIN Members b 
ON b.city_id = a.id  
GROUP BY b.city_id
```

Comment: Worked but without DISTINCT in the COUNT function .

Comment: Should be COUNT(DISTINCT b.id)

Comment: hey, If I have another table named 'posts' and it has 'city_id' attribute , can I get the same result and add how much posts in each city ?

something like this:
city_name , members_count , posts_count
Newyork , 15 , 20
Los Angles , 12 , 30

Comment: you can use the same method just add another join. But be careful when using JOIN, because if there are no results in the Members/Cities table, you wont get any results for that city. To get results for citys that dont have any members/posts use LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT
         c.name AS city_name,
         COUNT(m.id) AS counter
    FROM Members m
    JOIN Cities c ON m.city_id = c.id
```

Comment: Ok, I've just made a _rollback_ :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    cities.name as city_name, 
    count(cities.id) as counter
from 
    members inner join cities 
on 
    members.city_id = cities.city.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT c.name city_name, COUNT(m.id) counter
FROM Cities c INNER JOIN Members m
ON c.id = m.city_id
GROUP BY c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select city.name, count(member.id)
from city
inner join members
on city.id = members.city_id
group by city.name
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: INNER JOIN will not show any cities with zero members. So if the user needs to show cities that have zero, they should use LEFT JOIN instead.